# out of bounds exception, when the list is populated with objects

Tags: java

so I have no idea why im getting a outofbound error in this line

```
            bCountry = countriesList.get(loc);
```

in my menu im asking the user to enter a two letter country code, i trim the whitespace, and covert it to uppercase because the entire list is uppercase

then i pass along the code as a arguement in a constructor

```
 public CountryComponent(String bCode) throws IOException
{
    all = false;
    String aCode = bCode;

    getData();
}
```

the getData method pull in information from a csv file and creates objects with the data, then it calls a couple other methods to add in additional information to the objects

the issue is when I go to try and paint the specific object, everything else is fine

it just seems like the country code being typed in from the menu isnt being found in the list, and im not sure why

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:371)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:384)
at CountryComponent.paintComponent(CountryComponent.java:204)
```

the bottom line is the "red" colored exception, theres a much bigger list, idk if its needed.

Comment: The exception message says the index is `-1`. That's never valid no matter how many items are in `countriesList`. Hence the exception. Make it not be `-1`. Also please post relevant code in the future, and useful information such as the size of `countriesList` and the value of `loc` (of course, you indirectly posted the latter in your exception message).

Comment: `-1` is always out of bounds.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html   explains ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: sorry for this, I thought I had put enough info up there. I ended up figuring it out. thanks. I ended up just creating a new method, and calling it inside the getData method after all the objects were created so i made sure the lists were populated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have managed to give us a whole lot of code to look at, but none of it is the right code. Still the issue you have is that, when you call:

```
bCountry = countriesList.get(loc);
```

The value of `loc` is `-1`, and this is illegal.

Find out why the value is `-1`, and fix that.

Comment: thank you, the answer got me on the right path of thinking to solve the problem. Our class hasnt started learning about exceptions, I didnt know what the -1 meant, i only print the stack trace so i can go to which lines in my code that are giving me problems. Our class hasnt started with proper exception handling and understanding usages of catch, and the information you can get from what you put inside catch